# Google Maps Multiple Markers linking to the same url

Tags: javascript, google-maps, for-loop, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have an issue with Google Maps. I am trying to get it so that each of the markers link to the relevant pages on my website. However, currently all of the markers link to the same place and I am not sure why. I have set up an event listener within the for loop which specifies when the marker is clicked the user will be relocated to the correct specific web page. The issue appears to be that all of the markers are taking the first marker location and are linking to the same place. Any help would be massively appreciated.

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      styles: [{"featureType": "all", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [{"saturation": 36},{"color": "#333333"},{"lightness": 40}]},{"featureType": "all", "elementType": "labels.text.stroke", "stylers": [{"visibility": "on"},{"color": "#ffffff"},{"lightness": 16}]},{"featureType": "all", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]},{"featureType": "administrative", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [{"color": "#fefefe"},{"lightness": 20}]},{"featureType": "administrative", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [{"color": "#fefefe"},{"lightness": 17},{"weight": 1.2}]},{"featureType": "landscape", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#f5f5f5"},{"lightness": 20}]},{"featureType": "poi", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#f5f5f5"},{"lightness": 21}]},{"featureType": "poi.park", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#dedede"},{"lightness": 21}]},{"featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [{"color": "#ffffff"},{"lightness": 17}]},{"featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "geometry.stroke", "stylers": [{"color": "#ffffff"},{"lightness": 29},{"weight": 0.2}]},{"featureType": "road.arterial", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#ffffff"},{"lightness": 18}]},{"featureType": "road.local", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#ffffff"},{"lightness": 16}]},{"featureType": "transit", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#f2f2f2"},{"lightness": 19}]},{"featureType": "water", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{"color": "#e9e9e9"},{"lightness": 17}]}]  });

    setMarkers(map);
    }

    // Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for the
    // order in which these markers should display on top of each other.
    var beaches = [ ['Test', Latitude, Longitude, 4], ['Test1', Latitude, Longitude, 4], ['Test2', Latitude, Longitude, 4], ['Test3', Latitude, Longitude, 4] ]
function setMarkers(map) {

    var image = {
      url: 'open.png',
      // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
    };

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
      var beach = beaches[i];
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2]},
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: beach[0],
        zIndex: beach[3]
      });

      bounds.extend(marker.position);


      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
          return function () {
             window.location.href = "http://localhost/" + beach[0];
          }
      })(marker, i));

    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

      var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
        map.setZoom(11);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with variables assigned in loops.  The value of beach is left pointing to the last entry in the table when the loop exits.

You have two options:

1. use a property of the marker that is clicked (`this.getTitle()`)
2. use function closure (as is used for `marker` and `i`) in the event listener.

Simplest solution (#1):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/" + this.getTitle();
  }
})(marker, i));
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8b42qe6k/)

Function closure solution (#2):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i, link) {
  return function() {
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/" + link;
  }
})(marker, i, beach[0]));
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8b42qe6k/2/)

Comment: I can confirm that both methods work, thank you for your help!